# TableCellEditor class not working

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to add button at the end of each row, so far i have used cellRenderer to do so.And I have been successful for displaying buttons in every row like in snapshot.
[image: Table populated with buttons in each row]
But when i click on the buttons no action takes place.
i want to call a new frame when clicked on button.
following is my source code:

1.For Populating Jtable

```
try
{
    String url="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=c:\\ninedots.accdb";
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    String sql1="SELECT RMA_No,CallDate,Source,Item,BookingDesc,Customer,Contact,CallType,CallMode,MaterialRequired,TotalMaterialRequiredCost,AssignedTo,CallStatus FROM RMA_Master WHERE (((CallDate) Between #"+fromdate1+"# And #"+todate1+"#)) AND CallStatus='"+Status+"'";
    PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(sql1);
    ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
    dtm=(DefaultTableModel) DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs);
    dtm.addColumn("Action");                
    table.setModel(dtm);
    table.getColumn("Action").setCellRenderer(new ButtonCellRenderer());
    table.getColumn("Action").setCellEditor(new ButtonCellEditor());
    rs.close();
    pst.close();
    con.close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.err.print("Exception: ");
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

2.ButtonCellRenderer Class

```
 public class ButtonCellRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (value != null) {
            setText("Edit" + value.toString());
        } else {
            setText("Edit");             
        }
        if (isSelected) {
            setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
            setForeground(table.getForeground());
            setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

3.ButtonCellEditor Class

```
 public class ButtonCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

    /**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JButton editor;
    private Object value;
    private int row;
    private JTable table;

    public ButtonCellEditor() {
        editor = new JButton();
        editor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  if (table != null) {
                        fireEditingStopped();
                        TableModel model = table.getModel();
                        if (model instanceof DefaultTableModel) {
                            ((DefaultTableModel) model).removeRow(row);
                        }
                    }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        this.table = table;
        this.row = row;
        this.value = value;
        if (value != null) {
            editor.setText("Delete row " + value.toString());
        } else {
            editor.setText("Delete Me");
        }
        if (isSelected) {
            editor.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            editor.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
            editor.setForeground(table.getForeground());
            editor.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
        }
        return editor;
    }


}
```

Please Suggest Solutions For Following Problem.or where i am doing mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for a custom renderer/editor that allows you to add a button with a custom `Action` to any column.

The only code you write is the `Action` so it is easy to implement:

```
Action delete = new AbstractAction()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JTable table = (JTable)e.getSource();
        int modelRow = Integer.valueOf( e.getActionCommand() );
        ((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).removeRow(modelRow);
    }
};
```

Comment: It worked..can you help me optimizing the code.? because now it has become quite complex :( I mean can I delete cellEditor Class now?